# qTip2 - too much recursion

Tags: jquery, qtip, qtip2

I'm using jQuery v@1.8.1 and have this two files included in my HTML:

```
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And I'm trying to use qTip like this:

```
<em class="hasTooltip">test</em>

$('.hasTooltip').qtip({ // Grab some elements to apply the tooltip to
    content: {
        text: 'My common piece of text here'
    }
});
```

It's the easiest example from qTip [website](http://qtip2.com/guides#gettingstarted.static). But I receive this message in the console "too much recursion".

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/7L4xrtc9/1/

Comment: It seams that Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.0 (http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js) is causing this problem.
After I removed it, the tooltips work.